When is it useful to give a vaccine post-infection?
I was reading this answer about the rabies vaccine, which explains that giving the vaccine post-exposure is effective because the vaccine stimulates a more rapid immune response than the infection itself would. From this, I inferred that the vaccine buys the immune system enough time to combat the virus, which would otherwise cause death before a natural immune response could fully develop. My question is: When this principle apply to other vaccines? My instinct is to say it would fail in the case of faster-acting diseases such as measles or the flu, because a natural immune response would have already been triggered before the vaccine could "teach" the immune system to fight off the pathogen.  Is that correct?  If so, would it mean that if we could figure out a way to get more vaccines to be effective more quickly (say, within hours or days, instead of the weeks or longer many vaccines take to induce even partial immunity), post-infection vaccination would be more generally effective, assuming the vaccine was administered as soon as possible after exposure, instead of rabies being a rare exception?
On the other hand, what about with dormant infections?  In the case of HPV in particular, I’ve read that vaccination is ineffective once the virus is already inside cells, as the immune system can’t target it there. That would seem to suggest that vaccines generally work by triggering an immune response that prevents a pathogen from entering the relevant cells in the first place.  And yet, the shingles vaccine prevents illness from a virus that's already infected the person and is dormant. So why does that work, but post-infection vaccination against HPV wouldn't?

The short answer is that it's always better to prevent an illness than to treat it. The only time this doesn't hold true is when prevention is riskier than the illness.
(I'll not address HPV, as it's a seperate question. Feel free to post it as such.)
For every vaccine, medication, or anything else we put into our bodies, a risk to benefit ratio exists. If the risk of putting something into our body is high, we don't take it unless the benefit is greater than the risk. E.g. We don't usually eat spoiled fruit, but if you are starving and the risk is death, the risk of eating spoiled food is low compared to the benefit (it might save you from starving.)
The risk of death from rabies is as close to 100% as it can be without being 100%*, so the risk very, very high, and the benefit is life. So the risk of post-exposure vaccine, which (especially with rabies immune globulin) has been found to prevent rabies once exposure has occurred, is very low comparatively.  The history of post-exposure rabies vaccine goes back to 1885 and Louis Pasteur. It was mostly because of the period it was developed in that the vaccine was given post-exposure. Most vaccines don't work post-exposure. Look at Ebola, a deadly virus. There's no post exposure vaccine, just treatment, which is not guaranteed, and much more expensive, and of limited availability, than vaccine.
We are far from those days. Modern vaccines are much safer than some earlier vaccines were, so, again, prevention is better a cure.
The significant medical problem following exposure to influenza virus aside from the usual (and very uncomfortable) illness is pneumonia. Even with treatment, roughly 30,000 people will die in the US alone  from complications of influenza every year (some years are worse than others). Depending on the year, many more will be prevented by pre-exposure vaccination (in the US, 6 million in 2022-23 according to CDC estimates.)
Usually, people cannot pinpoint the exact moment of exposure to a virus, and by the time the illness becomes known, it will be more difficult to treat than to have prevented it, so the "what if" scenario you propose would result in treatment failures and illness. A vaccine is relatively simple; it's not like we have sensors available to warn us of an exposure, and if we had tests available, to take the test every time we're exposed to people would be impossible, both financially and because of human behavior. Once the virus has started to cause symptoms, eradicating the virus is treatment, not prevention, and doesn't work uniformly. The risk to benefit ratio of this approach is untenable, for rabies, for influenza, for measles, even for chicken pox.
Shingles occurs when your natural ability to fight the virus is decreased. When this occurs, the dormant virus gets reactivated and starts to replicate and spread. This will result in shingles, sometimes, disseminated shingles or sometimes (rarely) something worse. When the vaccine works, it does so by boosting immunity to the virus so that it can be kept dormant and/or destroyed before it causes shingles.
*To my knowledge, there have been only ~15 known survivors of rabies (once symptoms started) so far in the world. Which should illustrate why treatment is less desirable than prevention.

Interestingly I came across a paper a while ago that looked at seroprevalence in humans (not sure if it was this one: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8254041/) but it implied, as does the linked one, that rabies infection is much more common than suspected and largely survivable so long as it doesn't progress to the classic rabies neurological symptoms.

@bob1 - I answered another rabies question, and became aware at that time that there are people in remote areas where there is a high incidence of rabies that have IgG to rabies virus. At the time, it was unexplained, but clearly, there was exposure. So, yeah. But, I've now had PEP three times, and I wouldn't have it any other way!

Yes, I'm not in a rabies country, but I'm very glad the vaccine exists and works as PEP. It might have been your previous answer that made me aware of the incidence. Route of exposure could explain it, though there are those couple of intriguing cases where there's no evidence of bite. Though I guess there's still risk of contact with nervous tissue via inhalation.
